# S3 Signature Mismatch on URL with VersionId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am curious why I am getting a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error on a Versioned URL for an object in my S3 bucket (by appending `versionId=abdcd`).

When the URL has the following pattern:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object.tar.gz
```

everything seems to work fine.  However as soon as I add the `versionId` query string, I get the signature mismatch error

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object.tar.gz?versionId=abcde
```

The method for accessing the object is controlled by `CloudFormation::Init`'s `source` property, as describe [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html)

> S3 Bucket
>
> The following example downloads a zip file from an Amazon S3 bucket
>   and unpacks it into /etc/myapp:
>
> Note You can use authentication credentials for a source. However, you
>   cannot put an authentication key in the sources block. Instead,
>   include a buckets key in your S3AccessCreds block. For an example, see
>   the example template. For more information on Amazon S3 authentication
>   credentials, see AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication. JSON
>
> "sources" : {   "/etc/myapp" :
>   "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myapp.tar.gz"   }

**This is not a permissions issue** because it works fine when there's no `versionId` query string.  I am curious why the signing method is failing by just adding that? And how can I fix it?

I read up [AWS's Signature V4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) but I don't see anything that explains why this is not working?  It seems that query strings are only supposed to be used for [auth headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)?

Comment: Agree 100%, this is **not** a permissions issue.  I wonder whether CloudFormation correctly supports using versioned objects here... the documentation seems a little bit sparse.  Specifying `?versionId=...` in the query string is correct, lowercase `v` capital `I`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am wondering if there's a work around? The documentation is very sparse on this indeed! Maybe it's time to hack it with `UserData`?

Comment: is there any update on this? I've been trying this so long but haven't got past to this error.